# Emberjs specific SCSS file for my component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

We just started working with Emberjs and what I would like is to create a new custom component which is complete on its on. This means it has its own js file, its own template file and its own styling. The first two I already get when I generate a new component with the ember cli. The last one, styling, I haven't found how I can create a CSS/SCSS file that is only loaded when I load a given component. Is there such a thing?

Comment: I strongly doubt you really want to dynamically load CSS, which is what you seem to be saying. Writing your CSS modularly is a wonderful idea, but loading each bit of CSS when each component is invoked is neither necessary nor desirable.

Comment: Hi Valanto, you want a unique style to be loaded for each component right ?

Comment: What do you mean by "loaded"?

Comment: I don't necessarily want it to be loaded dynamically but I would like the component to have it's own css/scss file and loaded only if I choose to use the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ember-components-css](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-component-css) seems to do exactly what you want.
You can also have a look at [ember-css-modules](https://github.com/salsify/ember-css-modules).

With Ember-components-css you'll be able to do the following:

```
app/my-component/styles.css
& {  // ampersand refers to the component itself (parent selector)
  padding: 2px;
}
.urgent {
  color: red;
}
```

and this will be generated:

```
.my-component-a34fba {
  padding: 2px;
}
.my-component-a34fba .urgent {
  color: red;
}
```

Which is what I think you do want right ?

And bonus, you can use preprocessors:

```
// app/styles/app.scss
@import "pod-styles"; or
// app/styles/app.less
@import "pod-styles"; or
// app/styles/app.styl
@import 'pod-styles'
```

Comment: I don't think either of those does dynamic loading which is what the OP apparently is looking for.

Comment: Hmm I wonder, I think he wants to load a css file with each component, and have it be unique to that component. Which is exactly what ember-components-css does ?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm pretty sure he wants that! He probably means *loaded* as *applied* and not loaded over the network.